# Facebook url leading to 404 page

Tags: html, facebook, url

In my [website](https://sprouty.netlify.app/products/moong.html), I have link to a facebook page search result (https://www.facebook.com/page/104839442303062/search/?q=Moong%20sprout). While testing on my end, this link works well, but while viewing on other device or incognito window, it leads to 404 page.

Does this happen because the user hasn't logged in facebook? If so, what can I do to make it the page visible for everyone?

Comment: Yes it looks like it is because the user is not logged in. And there is nothing you can do about it. Only Facebook can change that.

Comment: @WizKid Wierd! I tried it on mobile with facebook logged in (in browser), still page not found.

Comment: Then the URL doesn't work on mobile either. Also something only Facebook can fix.